# Aria-expanded is not working in the project

Tags: c#, html, css, blazor

```
 <ul class="list-unstyled topnav-menu float-end mb-0">
            <li class="dropdown notification-list topbar-dropdown">
                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle nav-user me-0 waves-effect waves-light" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" href="#" role="button" aria-haspopup="false" aria-expanded="false">
                    <img src="@obj.ImgUrl" alt="user-image" class="rounded-circle">
                    <span class="pro-user-name ms-1">
                        @obj.Users.FirstName @obj.Users.LastName <i class="mdi mdi-chevron-down"></i>
                    </span>
                </a>
```

The above code is the code for a dropdown in the navbar and it should open when clicked on the anchor tag i have given role as button and also the aria-expended is set to false and it should change to true when clicked but it is not working the dropdown does not expand, what should i do?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Where's the code that causes the dropdown to open and the aria attribute to change? It would be easier to help if you [create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and use [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) to make a live demo.